# Looker Studio Custom Query across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have multiple MySQL tables, like the following

- chat_18_4_2023
- chat_17_4_2023
- chat_16_4_2023
- chat_15_4_2023

etc

I am trying to use Looker Studio's custom query to select the data from all of these tables. The structure of every table is the same.

I have used the query as follows, which works perfectly in MySQL:

```sql
SET @sql = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name LIKE 'chat_%'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But when run in Looker Studio, this query produces an error.

I believe this is because of the following (taken from [the Looker Studio documentation](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6370296#custom-query))

> Custom SQL queries may only have a single statement.
>
> For example, the following will not work because it has multiple SQL statements:
>
> `DECLARE cost_per_tb_in_dollar FLOAT64 DEFAULT 4.2;`
>
> `SELECT total_bytes_billed / (1024 * 1024))* cost_per_tb_in_dollar)/(1024*1024))) FROM billing-table;`

I have tried reformatting the SQL statement, and asking ChatGPT to do the same, but the result every time is the same.

> Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Does anyone know how to correctly format a GoogleSQL query to do this?

Comment: Your MySQL tables are uploaded to BigQuery ?

Comment: @Jaytiger No, but as far as I'm aware the 'Custom Query' box doesn't use normal SQL and instead uses the same language as Google BigQuery, which is the slightly modified GoogleSQL.